# Wordpress : Conditional Tags Within Plugin

Tags: wordpress

Why can't use conditonal tags inside plugin? Here's the script:

```
/* enqueue */
function portfoliodetail_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'portfoliodetailjs', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'js/portfolio-detail.js', array('velocity'), null, true );
}

if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'portfoliodetail_enqueue' );
}
/* /enqueue */
```

the `is_singular( 'portfolio' )` (because the post type is *portfolio*) works well in theme directory file. But when it is written within plugin, it doesn't work.

Anybody willing to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your condition should be in the hook.**
it should be like this:

```
function portfoliodetail_enqueue() { 
   if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'portfoliodetailjs', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'js/portfolio-detail.js',    array('velocity'), null, true );
   }
}


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'portfoliodetail_enqueue' );
```

Comment: wow, quite simple. thanks a lot @jogesh-pi :D

let me accept this answer

Comment: Thanks Jogesh, some other people in there answers couldn't get this right: **Your condition should be in the hook.**.